# How to open bat files without window in C#

Tags: c#, batch-file

I want to run Batch files in C#.
Here's my code:

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace startr
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string appdata = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%appdata%");
            string path = appdata + @"\tempor.bat";
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path))
            {
                sw.WriteLine(@"net use z: \\192.168.1.3\SambaShare /u:192.168.1.3\pi raspberry");
                sw.WriteLine(@"del tempor.bat");
            }
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(path);
```

Any ideas?
I don't want to use `Process p = new Process();` if i don't have to.

Comment: Why are you using the command processor at all, instead of just doing mapping the drive from code with `WNetAddConnection2()`? No need to write a file, execute a batch file, or delete the file afterward. You can find the C# declarations at [PInvoke](http://pinvoke.net).

Comment: I dunno, it seems easier for me

Comment: You can map it with the function I mentioned in less code than you've written here to use the batch file.

Comment: For system administration the Windows Script Host is filled with stuff like this. The COM object WSHNetwork. In VBscript you do this `CreateObject("WScript.Network").MapNetworkDrive "Z:", "\\127.0.0.1\C$\Windows\System32", [bUpdateProfile]` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can stick to `Process.Start()` if you provide additional information to it using `ProcessStartInfo`:

```
var dir = "<Insert .bat directory here>";
var bat = "<Insert .bat filename here>";
Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo() { WorkingDirectory = dir, FileName = bat, WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden });
```

Adding `WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden` will hide the console-window for your batch-script.

Using your code this would probably look like:

```
string appdata = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%appdata%");
string bat = @"\tempor.bat";
string path = appdata + bat;
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path))
{
    sw.WriteLine(@"net use z: \\192.168.1.3\SambaShare /u:192.168.1.3\pi raspberry");
    sw.WriteLine(@"del tempor.bat");
}

System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo() { WorkingDirectory = appdata, FileName = bat, WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden });
```